# Split actionbar for a specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, split, android-actionbar

I have an activity with three fragments. Fragment A has 1 item in actionbar. Fragment B has 4 items in actionbar, and Fragment C has 1. So, I want to have split actionbar when I change to fragment B, but I don't want split action bar in A-C fragments, because there is no reason to fill de bottom of the screen with a bar only for one item.

Can I change actionbar mode when I change between fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done using Fragments as ActionBar is associated with the Activity. However, I tried what you are looking for with two activities and it worked.

Add the action bar in onCreateOptionsMenu in both the activities and then add
    getWindow().setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

right before onCreate method of the activity in which you want the split action bar to appear. Thats it. Simple isn't it. :)

You can also hide and show it using getActionBar.hide() and getActionBar.show() methods respectively.

(The only thing I missed is checking this with support libraries. Will try and update you on that as well)

Let me know if this helps you in some way. Happy coding :)